# Android textview gravity center

Tags: android

I have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#222222"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:max="5"
        android:progress="2">
   </SeekBar>
      <TextView android:id="@+id/fontsize00" 
        android:layout_width="25dp" 
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="C"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#222222">
   </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The size of the text changes with the change of the value of the spinner.
Even if at low values the text is in the center of the textview, at bigger values it is set lower.
Why is this happening?
[image]

Comment: Did my suggestion below work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because you are setting the `android:layout_height` of the layout manually. Try changing it to `wrap-content`.

And `TextView`, as you are probably aware, has some other padding methods. Where you can set some special padding.

Comment: Setting it to wrap_content doesn't solve the problem. I could manually set the padding if the spinner value is 4 or 5 but that is not the way it should work..

Answer (score 7):

It is caused by font padding. Text inside TextView frame is laid out according to additional padding for ascenders and descenders.
Font padding can be turned off by setting attribute of TextView widget:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```